# Time difference excel format

Tags: excel, datetime, time, difference, date-difference

I have a two dates in excel "1/2/2016 01:56:05" in A1 and "8/3/2016 06:21:46" in A2. How do I calculate the time difference between them in a format of days, hours and minutes?

I tried the below but doesn't seems to work:

=INT(A2-A1) & " days, " & TEXT(A2-A1,"h") & " hours, " & TEXT(A2-A1,"m") & " min"

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think it "doesn't seems to work"?

Comment: Not sure though....i tried changing to a smaller scale having 1/2/2016  1:56 in A1 and 1/2/2016  2:00 in A2 but the result displays as "0 days, 0 hours, 1 min". Its supposed to be "0 days, 0 hours, 4 min" right?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that TEXT(A2-A1,"m") is returning the Month value instead of the Minute value

Comment: @Dave: Seems you are right: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US. Very ugly that. German Excel does not do this. It differs between "M" for month and "m" for minute.

Comment: Any idea how to solve this to an output with "minutes"? Tried "mm" but doesn't work as well. :(

Comment: Marking this as a duplicate is a joke in my opinion. "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question." Surely "those answers do not fully address this question". So what shall the user3085606 do now? Really ask a new question? And this will also marked as duplicate then?

Comment: @user3085606: As said before, German Excel can differ between "M" as month and "m" as minute. Because English Excel seems can't, do `=INT(A2-A1) &" days, " & TEXT(--LEFT(TEXT(A2-A1,"hh:mm:ss"),2),"0")& " hours, "& TEXT(--MID(TEXT(A2-A1,"hh:mm:ss"),4,2),"0")& " min"`

Comment: @user3085606  Here's another formula:  `=INT(A2-A1) & " days, " & TEXT(MOD(A2-A1,1),"h "" hours, ""m "" minutes""")`

Comment: The elapsed form of [m] gives minutes not months so you could also try something like =TEXT(MOD(A2-A1,1/24),"[m]") to get the minutes

Comment: Just for another option `=TEXT(A2-A1,"0 \Da\y\s, ") & TEXT(A2-A1,"h \Hou\r\s m \mi\nut\e\s s \s\eco\n\d\s")`